# Как в массив JS добавить html код?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть небольшой "словарь" для смены языка на сайте. Все работает отлично, вот только на сайте есть текст с встроенной ссылкой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда делаю перевожу на другой язык(покажу на примере русского)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то на сайте он высвечивается прямым текстом. что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Покажите, как вы вставляете текст в html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй отдельно перевести весь текст вне ссылки, добавить класс элементу  и перевести его отдельно в вашем списке переводов.

Comment: оаоа, так всё получилось, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Splashny если ответ правильный, отметьте его галочкой. А за хороший ответ можете и "голос за" давать.